# Scala -- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/streaming/StreamingContext

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I am getting error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Here is my complete program:

```
object StatefulNetworkWordCount {
  def updateFunction(newValues: Seq[Int], runningCount: Option[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    val newCount = runningCount.getOrElse(0) + newValues.sum
    Some(newCount)
  }

    // Set checkpoint directory
    ssc.checkpoint("E:\\sparkdata")

    // Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

    // Split each line into words
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))

    // Count each word in each batch
    val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))

    // Update state using `updateStateByKey`
    val runningCounts = pairs.updateStateByKey[Int](updateFunction _)

    // Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
    runningCounts.print()

    ssc.start() // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination() // Wait for the computation to terminate
```

And my pom.xml file :///

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JDBC Connector Jar    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.bytecode</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Would be easier to trace if you provide the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

you are including different versions of spark.
you have both 2.1.1 and 1.6.0 .

you should use the same spark version for all spark dependencies

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered, to help future reader know that the question been solved. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers